# Typescript Error: setInterval - Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code:

```
let onSizeChangeSetInterval = setInterval(() => {...}, 30);
```

When I compile this code, I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR in src/components/popover/popover.component.ts(98,17): error TS2322: Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'number'.
>   src/modules/forms-ui/formly/types/daterange/picker.daterange.component.ts(186,9): error TS2322: Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use `window.setInterval` instead

Comment: Accessing `window` will break when trying to build the application on server side.

Comment: For those that may not know, plain 'old `setInterval` seems to return `NodeJS.Timeout` (per code inspection) but `window.setInterval` returns `number`.

Comment: I'm using `window.setInterval` in a vue cli project and I'm still getting the error. I have to type it as a `number`.

Comment: @Jyothu First check for the existance of window: `if (typeof window !== 'undefined'){}`

Answer (score 42):

Use [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype):

```
let onSizeChangeSetInterval: ReturnType<typeof setInterval> | undefined;
onSizeChangeSetInterval = setInterval(() => {...}, 30);
```

Answer (score 9):

By looking at `error TS2322` it looks like a TypeScript error rather than JavaScript one. Basically you are trying to cast type number variable to a timer one.

could you do instead ?

```
let onSizeChangeSetInterval:NodeJS.Timer;
onSizeChangeSetInterval = setInterval(() => {...}, 30);
```

Taken from

http://evanshortiss.com/development/nodejs/typescript/2016/11/16/timers-in-typescript.html

Comment: yeah. I think he could also use `var` instead of `let`.

Comment: I guess he could. But I would strongly suggest to use ES6 `let` or `const` and avoid using `var`. Var is not block-scoped so I would recommend to stop using it and fully switch to the first 2 type of variables. Embrace newer JavaScript (ES6) (https://hackernoon.com/js-var-let-or-const-67e51dbb716f)

Comment: the TypeScript compiler cannot differentiate setInterval from `@types/node` or from `lib.dom.ts`, use `window.setInterval` to desambiguate, the return type should be `number` in the browser.