# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'TeardownLogic'

Tags: angular, observable, teardown

I made a service that returns a time `Observable`,

```
time = new Observable(observer =>
    setInterval(() => observer.next(new Date().toString()), 1000)
);
```

However, it gives the following error,

> ERROR in src/app/services/date.service.ts(11,5): error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'TeardownLogic'.

I found this solution([Typescript Error: setInterval - Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'number'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189729/typescript-error-setinterval-type-timer-is-not-assignable-to-type-number)) but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you have some issue while declaring type of time or something else. Have a look to below solution:

```
export class AppComponent {
  time: Observable<string>;
  constructor() {
    this.time= new Observable(observer => {
      setInterval(() => {
        observer.next(new Date().toString());
        observer.complete();
      }, 1000);
    });
    this.time.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value)
    })
  }
}
```

Output in console

```
Mon Nov 18 2019 21:18:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: @Krishanu No observer.complete() This line just stopped subscription. I cant say untill i see your code